# Can't declare Class field type of the other class

Tags: c++, class

Why i can't declare Class field type of the other class? This gives me C4430 error:

```
//Entity.h file
    class Entity
    {
    public:
        Box test;
    };


    class Box
    {
    public:
        double length;   // Length of a box
        double breadth;  // Breadth of a box
        double height;   // Height of a box
    };
```

Comment: Define class box first and then class entity. In this sequence, the class entity does not yet know that there is a class box defined next.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Class `Entity` needs to know about class `Box`, before the definition. Also, as you're including the object of and not the pointer to `Box` in your `Entity` class, it also needs to know the size of `class Box` (full definition of `Box` class is needed) and the definition of the members (as it will access `Box::Box` in order to initialize the actual field), so you need the full definition of `Box` before making it a field in your `Entity` class.

```
    class Box
    {
    public:
        double length;   // Length of a box
        double breadth;  // Breadth of a box
        double height;   // Height of a box
    };

    class Entity
    {
    public:
        Box test;
    };
```